# What is a "half" in Bitcoin?

Tags: terminology, reward-schedule

I saw in an article something about a Bitcoin algorithm half in 2020. What exactly is this? I have tried looking this up but I couldn't find anything that told me what it was only a [website counting down to the next](https://bitcoinblockhalf.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin controls the supply of coins by halving the miner subsidy (reward) every 210,000 blocks or roughly every 4 years. The miner subsidy started at 50BTC. See [Mining Reward](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining#Reward).

This is a simple chart that illustrates the Bitcoin distribution schedule:

[image: Bitcoin Distribution]

Comment: It's worth noting that the long tail is very long, but the subsidy is almost zero for the majority of it.